# Swift / IBAction / CGRect on UIView.label

Tags: ios, swift

I want a top bar (UIView) to move as soon as a button is pressed.

```
@IBAction func displayOptions(sender: AnyObject) {

self.topBar.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: self.topBar.frame.size.width, height: self.topBar.frame.size.height)

}
```

Is not working. The UIView doesn't move.

I have tryed to set the original.x/y in the viewDidLoad, but it didn't changed anything.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    var xvalue = self.topBar.frame.origin.x
    var yvalue = self.topBar.frame.origin.y

    xvalue = 0
    yvalue = 0

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Help is very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: PS: self.dateLabel.alpha = 0 works perfectly

Comment: r u using auto layout?

Comment: yes I do! well thank you that really might be the problem

Comment: Moving a top bar is odd...

Comment: @DavidSeek, np you should change the constraints if you are working with auto layout rather than changing the frame .

Comment: @karthik. thank you mate. it worked and moved. please answer, so i can give a thumbs up

Comment: @terence I'll edit my post to show you, what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the constraints if you are working with auto layout rather than changing the frame.